# CURL with PHP exec() fails using Amazon EC2 Windows Server IIS7

Tags: php, curl, iis-7, amazon-ec2

I have the below code

```
<?php
$e = exec('curl');
var_dump($e);
?>
```

But it doesnt seem to be printing anything. Doing `exec('ping google.com');` returns something though.

1) I know `curl` is working fine because typing that in the command prompt works.

2) I tried moving `curl.exe` to the same location as my script but that didnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are running this through the browser after deployed to your apache. So you should check your apache error log. And you'll find this at there:

```
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Another thing can be, you may not have access to the `curl` from your apache. These are all just guess.

**UPDATE:** As per the observation of the `user1258600`: the output appeared on the browser after adding `2>&1` at the end of the command.

Comment: I am using IIS instead of Apache but you got it quite right. I added ` 2>&1` to the end of my command and what you typed appear on my browser when I ran the php file. if you want to change your answer a little I will have it marked as the answer. Many thanks!

Comment: I have updated the answer, and added your observation.